# Route configuration in ASP Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I Have a problem configuring routes in ASP Core.

In `Startup.cs` I used default configuration: `services.AddMvc()` in `ConfigureServices()` and `app.UseMvc()` in `Configure()`.

Now I have a simple controller in the same assembly:

```
[Route("/api/[controller]")]
public class TestController: Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Test()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Request `/api/test/test` doesn't fire

But if i add `[HttpGet("test")]` or `[Route("test")]` it works well.

However I'd like to support convention over configuration in case route attribute is not specified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

Comment: this is very strange as I've tried this approach before any of others. thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you add `[Route("/api/[controller]")]` annotation to Controller, the default routing configured in `Startup.cs` will ignore this Controller.

So you either need to specify URL suffix **for each** of your actions inside that Controller by adding `[Route("")]` attribute above them:

```
[Route("/api/[controller]")]
public class TestController: Controller
{
    [Route("test")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string Test()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

**Or** specify in Controller annotaion that the routing should use **action names** as part of URL :

```
[Route("/api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class TestController: Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Test()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     [Route("/api/[controller]")]
 public class TestController: Controller
 {
    [HttpGet(namOf(Test),Name=namOf(Test))]
    public string Test()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.